# NamedJDBCTemplate Parameters is list of lists

Tags: java, jdbc, kotlin, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable t WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN (VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4))
```

And it would select any records where `t.a == 1 AND t.b == 2`  or `t.a == 3 AND t.b == 4`.

This seems to work just fine.

However, I can't figure out a clean way to specify the parameter to `NamedJDBCTemplate`. I tried giving it a list of lists (i.e., `List<List<int>>`), but it seems to blow up doing that.

```
val query = "SELECT * FROM someTable t WHERE (t.a, t.b) IN (VALUES :values)"

namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, mapOf("values" to listOf(listOf(1, 2), listOf(3, 4))))
```

I also tried manually converting the value to a string, but that doesn't make it happy either.

```
namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, mapOf("values" to "(1, 2), (3, 4)"))
```

(I'm actually working in Kotlin, but that shouldn't have an effect on this question)

Comment: post the code you did try.

Comment: I've added the code I've tried.

Comment: which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: DB2 LUW. The query itself works just fine in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your values in as a collection of object arrays:

```
namedJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, ImmutableMap.of(Lists.newArrayList(new Object[] {1,2}, new Object[]{3,4})));
```

We use Google Guava to instantiate collections hence why I've used `ImmutableMap` and `Lists`, but obviously you can go about creating them how you wish.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Looks like a list of lists doesn't work, but a list of arrays does. I used arrays of strings and they worked just fine.