# How to execute multi batch delete in JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I want to delete multiple database entries at once. Each entry should only be deleted if 3 fields match (here: name, email, age).

If I'd just wanted to delete by a single property, I'd go for:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE (email) IN (?)";

JdbcTemplate template;
template.execute(sql, Arrays.asList(emails...));
```

But what if my condition is formed by multiple fields?

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE (name, email, age) IN (?, ?, ?)";

JdbcTemplate template;
template.execute(sql, ...); ???
```

The condition should always match all 3 fields (`AND`)!

Comment: You need to be more specific.  If you have names `'a', 'b', 'c'` and ages `20, 22, 24`, what would that mean?  Would you delete all 9 combinations *(`['a',20], ['a',22], ['a',24], ['b',20], ['b',22], ['b',24], ['c',20], ['c',22], ['c',24]`)*?  Or just three *(`['a',20], ['b',22], ['c',24]`)*?  What if you specified 3 names and 2 ages?  Also, which DBMS are you using?  PostgreSQL and MySQL, for example, have very different capabilities, and even different syntax in some cases.

Comment: I'm using mysql, and I eg only want to delete entries that match ("john", "john@test.de", 24). and I want to provide more tuples at once. But each row must match the tuples. So I want to delete by connecting the fields by `AND`.

Comment: You miss my point.  If you give `([john], [john@test.de], [24])` then it's easy.  If you give `([john, larry], [john@test.de, larry@gmail.com], [24, 26])` then it's ambiguous.  There are 8 different combinations of those arrays.  If there is a John/john@test.de who is 24 ***and also*** a John/john@test.de who is 26, should both be deleted?  OR does the 26 only apply to Larry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NamedJDBCTemplate Parameters is list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261515/namedjdbctemplate-parameters-is-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`batchUpdate(sql, batchArgs, argTypes)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-int:A-) method.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE name = ? AND email = ? AND age = ?";
int[] argTypes = { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER };

List<Object[]> batchArgs = new ArrayList<>();
batchArgs.add(new Object[] { "John Doe", "john@example.com", 42 });
batchArgs.add(new Object[] { "Jane Smith", "jane@example.com", 47 });
. . .

JdbcTemplate template = ...;
int[] rowCounts = template.batchUpdate(sql, batchArgs, argTypes);
```

Comment: Would `batchUpdate()` perform better than just collecting multiple delete statements and executing them as batch? Eg `DELETE FROM persons WHERE name = :name AND email = :email AND age = :age` could be collected with `preparedStatement.addBatch(sql)` and send to db via `ps.executeBatch()`.

Comment: @membersound That is what `JdbcTemplate` does behind the scenes. What else did you think the `Jdbc` part of the name meant? It's a convenience class for doing JDBC.

Answer (score 2):

A `batchUpdate` is what you are looking for here. You would need to change/tweak your query a little bit though.

If you can pass a list of objects (you must match the class members with the values on the SQL query), it can be done automatically:

```
private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

// class People { String name; String email; Integer age; }
final String sql = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE name = :name AND email = :email AND age = :age";
final SqlParameterSource[] batchArgs = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(people.toArray()); // List<People>
final int[] results = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, batchArgs);
logger.debug("{} record(s) inserted successfully", results.length);
```

The other approach would be what @Andreas [proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471835/4695271).

---

I would also recommend to use, always, parameterized queries: `DELETE FROM persons WHERE name = :name AND email = :email AND age = :age`.